# C++ copy constructor behaviour

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, variable-assignment

There is a part of C++ code I don't really understand.
Also I don't know where should I go to search information about it, so I decided to ask a question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
    public:
        Test();
        Test(Test const & src);
        Test& operator=(const Test& rhs);
        Test test();
        int x;
};

Test::Test()
{
    cout << "Constructor has been called" << endl;
}

Test::Test(Test const & src)
{
    cout << "Copy constructor has been called" << endl;
}

Test& Test::operator=(const Test& rhs)
{
    cout << "Assignment operator" << endl;
}

Test Test::test()
{
    return Test();
}

int main()
{
    Test a;
    Test b = a.test();

    return 0;
}
```

Why the input I get is

```
Constructor has been called
Constructor has been called
```

?
a.test() creates a new instance by calling "Test()" so that's why the second message is displayed. But why no copy constructor or assignment called?
And if I change "return Test()" to "return *(new Test())" then the copy constructor is called.

So why isn't it called the first time?

Comment: The assignment-operator is not called because there's no assignment in `Test b = a.test();`. It's copy-initialization.

Comment: @DyP: `But why no copy constructor or assignment called?`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ? (of course the copy-ctor isn't called due to copy elision; I just wanted to point out that even though it looks like assignment, it is no assignment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compilers are very smart. Both copies - returning from `test` and initialising `b` (not this is not an assignment) - are elided according to the following rule (C++11 §12.8):

> when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

Compilers are allowed to do this even if it would change the behaviour of your program (like removing your output messages). It's expected that you do not write copy/move constructors and assignment operators that have other side effects.

Note that is only one of four cases in which copy elision can occur (not counting the as-if rule).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explaination! :)

Answer (score -2):

The call to a.test() returns by value and this value is then assigned to b "copying" the return value.  This invokes the copy constructor.

Comment: That is what is not happening because of copy elision.

Comment: what about this `Test a; Test *x = new Test(a);`?