# Empty default constructor, copy constructor and copy assignment: Why with a singleton the member variables are not random?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, singleton

I am studying constructor, copy constructors and copy assignment a while and I read a fair amount of contents mainly from here as [In which situations is the C++ copy constructor called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206359/in-which-situations-is-the-c-copy-constructor-called) and [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three?noredirect=1&lq=1) and others, but I still no deeply understanding their exactly behavior. I am performing some tests with the class **Boo** and **Foo** bellow and their results are not the ones that I was expecting. In the **class Boo** I explictly declared its default constructor, copy constructor and copy assingment, and I defined them to do nothing. From this I was expecting that the objects from this class would have **member variables** with **random values**, what was indeed observed. Nevertheless, this behavior was not seen with the objects from the **class Foo**. The only difference between these classes are that the later is a singleton, but its default constructor, copy constructor and copy assignment still explicit declared and defined to do nothing. From this I state my question: **Why the values of the member variables of objects from class Foo are not randomly initialized, but always has de same value of "0" and " "?**

```
#include <iostream>

class Boo {
    private:
        int x;
        char y;

    public:
        int getInt() { return x; }
        char getChar() { return y; }
        Boo () { std::cout << "Boo default constructor\n"; }
        Boo ( const Boo& other ) { std::cout << "Boo copy constructor\n"; }
        Boo& operator= ( const Boo& other) { std::cout << "Boo copy assinment\n";
                                            return *this;}

};

class Foo {
    private:
        int x;
        char y;
        static Foo *instance;

    protected:
        Foo() { std::cout << "Foo default constructor\n"; }
        Foo ( const Foo& other ) { std::cout << "Foo copy constructor\n"; }
        Foo& operator=( const Foo& other) { std::cout << "Foo copy assignment\n"; }

    public:
        static Foo & uniqueInst();
        int getInt() { return x; }
        char getChar() { return y; }
};

Foo *Foo::instance = 0;

Foo & Foo::uniqueInst(){
    if(!instance) instance = new Foo();
    return *instance;
};

int main(){
Boo b1; // default constructor
Boo b2; // default constructor
Boo b3 = b1; // copy constructor

b2 = b1;

std::cout << b1.getInt() << std::endl; // Random values since the constructor does nothing
std::cout << b1.getChar() << std::endl;

std::cout << b2.getInt() << std::endl; // Random values since the copy assignment does nothing
std::cout << b2.getChar() << std::endl;

std::cout << b3.getInt() << std::endl; // Random values since the copy constructor does nothing
std::cout << b3.getChar() << std::endl;


Foo *foo;
foo = &Foo::uniqueInst(); // defaulf construtor

std::cout << foo << std::endl;
std::cout << foo->getInt() << std::endl; // Why not random values?
std::cout << foo->getChar() << std::endl;

};
```

Comment: That's because "all values are 0" is a perfectly valid random result.

Comment: I second that. Either luck or something compiler/operating system dependent can be valid here. You can't depend on it.

Comment: I think you will find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032638/default-variable-value

Comment: You'll see the same with `Boo` if you do, say, `Boo& b1 = *new Boo();`. Apparently, your compiler/OS happen to zero-initialize heap memory. This is just an implementation detail; e.g. with MSVC the outcome is [garbage all around](http://rextester.com/EBZ45038)